# How to select from union result?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL script like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

now how to select again from the union result?

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
);
```

Comment: What do you even mean by your question? Select again?  Union result?  What is union result?

Comment: You could put all of your expression in brackets and put it after another expression, e.g. "Select salary from... where salary not in (your query)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put an alias for the inner query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
) as something;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for this:

```
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
    )
    WHERE ...
```