# Error 1064: UNION keyword breaking query, what is the proper syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have this query, which works fine:

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  message m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

Now if I try to do a `UNION` of two `SELECT`s on the `message` table, the query breaks because of `Error 1064`.

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  message (
    (SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1)
  ) AS m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is...I've read many questions related to `UNION`, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923077/how-to-select-from-union-result), and it seems that I'm running it properly.

Comment: Skip those parentheses not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extraneous `message` here:

FROM
  message (
    (SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1)
  ) m

You can fix this as:

```
FROM ((SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2)
      UNION
      (SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1)
     ) m
```

However `OR` is probably a better approach:

```
FROM ((SELECT *
       FROM message
       WHERE (to_id, from_id) = ( (1, 2), (2, 1) )
     ) m
```

You don't even need a subquery for this.  You can move the filtering condition to the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses in the outer query.

Comment: @intrepid . . . That actually explains (with a bit of detail) that the index will be used for the `OR`, so I am rather confused by your comment.

Answer (score 2):

remove inside parenthesis

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1
  ) AS m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: Inside parenthesis works fine actually, apparently it's just because of the extraneous `message` on the first `SELECT ... FROM message`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. After your first `from` you wrote `message` which is not needed as alias for table name is giving after the query `m` and table name `message` is already using on right place where it is needed to get the record.

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
----- message is removed from here as it is not needed.
  (
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1
  ) AS m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way - without union

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE (to_id,from_id) in ((1,2),(2,1))
  ) AS m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: why it is down voted?  Proper explanation is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I remove UNION and only use a query. It's more fast too

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM message WHERE (to_id = 1 AND from_id = 2) OR (to_id = 2 AND from_id = 1)
  ) AS m
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999
LIMIT
  100
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery) here; it can rather be simplified as a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  m.*,
  `to`.*,
  `from`.*
FROM
  message AS m 
  JOIN account AS `to` ON `to`.id = m.to_id
  JOIN account AS `from` ON `from`.id = m.from_id
WHERE
  m.id < 999999999 
  AND ( (m.to_id = 1 AND m.from_id = 2) 
         OR 
        (m.to_id = 2 AND m.from_id = 1)
      )
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: Can you please share your opinion on how the performance of that compares to the suggested `UNION` by Rick James on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591536/error-1064-union-keyword-breaking-query-what-is-the-proper-syntax/57591833)? That's actually what I had before.

Comment: Derived tables are materialized leading to more memory consumption; although in your case, performance difference might not be significant. Rick might have suggested UNION , as sometimes MySQL optimizer is not able to optimize the `OR` queries. You will need to run `Explain..` on both the queries and check the difference